# Android gradle api(platform(dependencies.firebaseBoM)) not importing Firebase plugins

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle, maven-bom

We're implementing a core library for a project that offers some common third-party libraries. I’m trying to define the **Firebase platform BOM** as an **api** dependency of an android library, but it doesn’t seem to be working, because the required Firebase plugins and libraries are missing in the final generated artifact.

This is a snippet of the build.gradle code used to define the dependencies:

```
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.0")

    api (""com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    api ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
    api ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx")
```

Any of the defined Firebase libraries (Analytics, Crashlytics nor Messaging) are included into the final artifact, but the Firebase BoM does correctly, as can be seen in the following **.pom** snippet:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
<artifactId>firebase-bom</artifactId>
<version>29.2.0</version>
<scope>implementation</scope>
</dependency>
....
</dependencies>
```

Anyone knows how to apply the BoM in a transitive way correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue, Any soultion?